# setting up pkg-config on Windows?

Tags: mingw, pkg-config, msvc12

I compiled pkg-config with MSVC and put the finished binary (*.exe) into **%PATH%**, with the aim to compile/install open source sources with MSVC trough MinGW shell and have the pkg-config install the *.pc files into some location set by **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** variable which I already set by using the Control Panel > environment variables.

However after installing compiled sources by using the "make install" no *.pc file is installed into **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** ??

What am I missing? and what can I do in order to have *.pc files intstalled into **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generation of *.pc files depends on application own build system. They may explicitly disable its generation when app compiled with MSVC, so you need to check Makefiles yourself for each project.

Comment: that's sad, it looks for now a workaround is to manually edit the *.pc files and copy/paste them into PKG_CONFIG_PATH :(